# Using a textfield to change form hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using Jquery with Ruby on Rails (3.1) and am having some problem with updating a hidden field via javascript.

Basically I have a textfield, and I'm trying to use ajax to update two different form hidden fields (one form for google checkout, one for amazon payments).

My Javascript looks like so:

```
$(function() {
  $('#payment_amount input').keyup(function() {
    var quantity = $('#payment_amount input').val();
    $("input[name='amount']").val("USD" + quantity);
    $("input[name='item_price_1']").val(quantity);
    return false;
  });
});
```

I have this in my application.js file for the time being (not yet in my .js.coffee, need to look into coffee script yet).

I think this javascript is correct, as I take the value from the input field, and it should update the input fields with the names 'amount' and 'item_price_1'. I thought maybe my selectors were wrong, so here's my html:

```
<input id="payment_amount" type="text" size="30" name="payment[amount]"> #textfield to change form hidden fiels

<form method="POST" action="https://checkout.google.com/api/checkout/v2/checkoutForm/Merchant/.... accept-charset="utf-8">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_price_1" value="20"/> #what I want to change
  ....
</form>

<form action="https://authorize.payments.amazon.com/pba/paypipeline" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="USD 20" > #also change this
</form>
```

This is all comes from a new.html.erb file. I do not have a new.js.erb file, do I need one?

Right now, this javascript doesn't seem to do a thing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$('#payment_amount input').keyup(function() {
     var quantity = $('#payment_amount input').val();
```

To this:

```
$('#payment_amount').keyup(function() {
     var quantity = $(this).val();
```

You're using the wrong selector for your payment_amount field. You can [see it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/9Yku6/).

Comment: `$('#payment_amount')` is more than enough, so jquery can use getElementById

Comment: Yep, had already edited it to remove the additional element type.

Comment: Wow guys, appreciate it a ton. Jsfiddle seems like an awesome tool as well. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, and yes, jsFiddle is amazing :).

Comment: And don't forget to click Accept if that answer does the trick for you.

Comment: Done, had to wait a bit to accept: you're too fast with your awesomeness.